# ASP.NET MVC SignalR refreshes every open page unintended

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am doing simple play around with SignalR, but I got stuck on really strange behaviour.
The call to the SignalR hub is set on a button click via mvc action:

```
<button href="' + "@Url.Action("ShowAlertMessage", "Edit")>
```

this is the SignalR action that is being called from MVC Action in controller:

```
public class NotificationHub : Hub
{
   public static void ShowAlertMessage()
   { 
      var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationPages>();
      context.Clients.All.sendAlert();
   }
}
```

and on another page I have this:

```
var notification = $.connection.NotificationHub;
console.log(notification);

notification.client.sendAlert = function () {
      alert('test me here');
}
```

the problem is that at the moment I click the button to invoke action from controller every single tab that I have opened related to the project is refreshed (without any logic to do so), even without any SignalR connection in it.
If I remove the SignalR call everything works as expected.
Is this a normal behaviour or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Firstly, it looks like the HTML of the button is malformed. Secondly, button elements do not have an `href` attribute; they do not transfer the page like an `a` element, they submit the parent form. This may explain the 'refreshing' behaviour you see, as the form itself is being sent to the server and the page redirected/refreshed.

Comment: sorry, the button is cutout it basically opens a PartialView, but does not refresh the page because it does not submit anything